# sails v0.10.0-rc7 unique constraint not working

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I upgraded my sails from rc4 to rc7 today, and the unique constraint on my model stopped working. note that in rc4 it used to work perfectly. and sails-mongo version on both versions i tried is: "sails-mongo": "^0.10.0-rc5"

Model attribute:

```
    emailAddress: {
        type: 'email',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
```

any issues?

Answer (score 1):

As already stated it's a bug in waterline/sails-mongo

I however advise against setting syncable to true as it was set to false by the developers for a reason (the [github bug report](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/152) explains more, also already stated igor)

If you require uniqueness you can just create an index in the DB manually. Not a great solution if you're deploying to different environments, but as a temporary work around it'll do.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

After all, we're using an RC for a piece of software at version 0.10, this kind of thing should be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's month old, just came here from Google, so for the reference, it is apparently known issue (check here for details: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/152)

As It's mentioned there, you can quick-fix this by setting

```
syncable = true
```

though that might imply some other problems (auto-migrating on no-sql databases)

Comment: Having this same issue now, in 2015, with Sails v11, anybody else?

Comment: @edencorbin try setting `migrate: 'safe',` in your `config/model.js` file.

Test this in your dev environment before you do this in production!

More info here: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings