# Unique property for models in Sails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, associations, sails.js

I am new to **SAILS**. I have the following models.

**models\Company.js**

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

name: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  unique: true

},
description: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true

}
}
};
```

**models\Project.js**

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

name: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},

key: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  unique: true
},

description: {
  type: 'string'
},

company: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},
startedDateTime: {
  type: 'datetime'
},
completedDateTime: {
  type: 'datetime'
},
members: {
  collection: 'ProjectMember',
  via: 'project',
  dominant: true
}
};
```

I need the model to be such that, there can be multiple companies but project must be unique for a particular company, but it can be same within two diffrent companies. How can I modify my models for getting this?

Comment: This link will help you [stack exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835136/sails-v0-10-0-rc7-unique-constraint-not-working). You can use 'mongoose' to get this facility.

Comment: Unique property is actually working. But what I need is that, the project Key must be unique in a company. But two different companies can have same project Keys.

Comment: Another, but not very future-friendly option, is to set the unique index on a company/project combo, so it wouldn't save dupes.

Comment: Please see my answer for [another question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29031869/2540397

Answer (score 1):

There are no such config options in sails.

But you could use lifecycle callbacks to handle this manually. 
You could add check beforeValidate and afterValidate functions.

Take a look here: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html

```
afterValidate: function(values, cb) {
    var params = {company: values.company};
    if (values._id) {
       params['_id'] = {$not: values._id};
    }
    Project.find(params).exec(function(err, projects) {
       if (projects.length > 0) return cb(new Error('Project already binded'));
       cb();
    });
}
```

This is only sample so it might not work please check conditions and events.